# Exercise 8.2 Harris Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

I am unfortunately unable to solve the following exercise:

> Let $\Lambda_1,\ \Lambda_2$ be two-planes in $\mathbb{P}^4$ meeting in one point $p$, and let $C_i\subset \Lambda_i$ be conic curves. Concretely:
> \begin{equation*} 
> \Lambda_1: W_0=W_1=0,\ \ \Lambda_2: W_3=W_4=0\end{equation*}
>
> 1. Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be disjoint given by the equations $C_1: W_2^2=W_3W_4,\ C_2: W_0W_1=W_2^2$. Show that in this case the join $J(C_1,C_2)$ is a quartic hypersurface.
> 2. Now look at $C_1: W_4^2=W_2W_3,\ C_2: W_1W_2=W_0^2$ i.e. non-disjoint conic curves. Show that now the join $J(C_1,C_2)$ becomes a cubic hypersurface.

Here is a link to Harris' book for the definitions of joins etc. http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/aconstant/Alg2/Bib/Harris_AlgebraicGeometry.pdf, p. 88,89.

Here is my approach: We have defined the join to be the image of $j: X\times Y -->\mathbb{G}(1,n),\ ([v],[w])\mapsto [v\wedge w]$. In this notation, I have implicitly used the Pluecker Embedding. My idea is to essentially look at what happens with the Pluecker Relations:
\begin{equation*}
W_{12}W_{34}-W_{13}W_{24}+ W_{14}W_{23}=0
\end{equation*}
However, when I plug in $v_1=v_2=1,\ w_4=w_5=0$ for the two rows in the matrix, I simply get 0=0 which is definitely not a quartic hypersurface. How do I get this hypersurface?

Any help would be very greatly appreciated :).

Comment: The join is not the image of the Pluecker embedding, it is the associated subvariety of $\mathbb P^4$. As for the matter of computing degree, which definition are you using? This is addressed later on in the book; one option would be to choose a generic line in $\mathbb P^4$ and compute its intersection with the join, i.e. determine the number of lines in the family that intersect the generic line.

Comment: I do not understand. It says on page 88 "the image of this map will be just the closure in $\mathbb{G}(1,n)$ of the locus of lines $\overline{xy}$ with $x\in X,y\in Y, x\neq y$." Isn't this the definition of a join? I mean he says that the join is the union of all the lines in this set; but this set solely contains lines, right?

Comment: As for the degree computation: I just look at the generating polynomials of the variety and look at the degree of them.

Comment: And in this case it is (supposed to be) a hypersurface, so it is determined by only one equation.

Comment: The image in the Grassmannian is the set parametrizing the lines (if you look again in Harris you'll see that he denotes this with a script $\mathscr J$ instead of a regular $J$). While the join is a hypersurface in $\mathbb P^4$ hence has dimension $3$, this subset of the Grassmannian, being the finite image of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ (the product of conics abstractly), has dimension $2$. For the degree computation, you may find it easier to work geometrically than to explicitly write down the equation of this hypersurface, but that could also just be my personal preference.

Comment: I am not familiar with this argumentation about degrees (as far as I know this is to be treated at a later stage in the book). But how do you know that the join is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^4$? And how do you know that the Grassmannian has dimension 2? How do you do it "geometrically"? If I just get the intuition/idea behind the task, I will be more than happy, as the calculation isn't the most interesting part :)

Comment: This is indeed treated later, but as Joe notes in the intro sometimes skipping around is necessary in this book. The Grassmannian is not of dimension $2$, it's the image of the map to the Grassmannian that is. This is because it is the image of a product of two curves, and because the mapping is finite-to-one. To see that the join is a hypersurface, just note that it is the total space of a family of lines parametrized by that $2$-dimensional subvariety of the Grassmannian, and the total space of any family of $n$-dimensional varieties over an $m$-dimensional base has dimension $n+m$...

Comment: ...Since the join is a threefold in $\mathbb P^4$, it is a hypersurface. As for the degree computation, as I said you start by choosing a generic line in $\mathbb P^4$. It will not intersect the two general planes hence neither of the conics, however for dimension reasons it must intersect any hypersurface. What remains is to show that the cardinality of this intersection is $4$ (or $3$ in the case that the conics meet).

And of course it may in fact be the case that you need to write down some determinantal description after all.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much for your help! First of all, why is the join a threefold? You jump around a lot in the book as I can see :). Which chapter should I read up on in order to understand this exercise? Also, in the hints, Harris said that one should use the construction of a join described in exercise 6.18. This I also unfortunately haven't been able to figure out. Do you think it is perhaps more sensible to treat the problem as in 6.18 instead of degrees?